# How to get array format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I am getting an array in AngularJs with factory function. This is the console

```
Array[0]
  0: "value1"
  1: "value2"
  length:2
```

But when i want to get the length of the array

```
console.log(array.length)
```

getting data from mysql in loopback

```
 app.factory("getFoo", function(Communications){
 return {
   getCommi: function(val,id){
    var array = [];
    var myVals = Communications.find({
                    filter: {
                        where: {
                            and : [{
                                communications_type_code : val
                            },{
                                object_id : id
                            }]
                        }
                    } 
                }, function(data){
                    for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
                        array[i] = data[i].contact_value;
                    }
                    return array;
        });

        return array;
      }
  }
});
```

The controller look like:

```
app.controller('usersFormCtrl', ['$scope','getFoo',function($scope,getFoo){
var emails = getFoo.getCommi(3,1);

setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.formModel.emails = [];
    for(var index=0; index < $scope.emails.length; index++){
        $scope.emails = emails;
    }
}, 0)
}])
```

I get that the length is 0. Why is that?

Comment: share more of your code. where you log in console and where you get the array?

Comment: How you are adding element to array? Kindly share. The display code of yours is proper and I think the issue is while you are adding the elements to array. Check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401124/how-to-display-the-array-length-in-console-with-javascript-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a timing issue. The first time you ask for the length it is indeed 0, but when you inspect the object a few seconds later with Chrome Dev Tools you are inspecting the live object which has now been filled.

You can confirm this by using `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(array);
}, 0)
```

You can checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460602/array-shows-0-as-length-when-it-has-elements-in-it) for further explanation

**UPDATE**

In angular, use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`. Like this:

```
$timeout(function(){
   console.log(array);
}, 0)
```

Comment: it's working. but since i am using angular i am using that with scope. I update my question.

Comment: @oded: I have updated my answer. Please let me know why the answer was downvoted

Comment: my mistaske. happen accidentley.

Answer (score 0):

The length property of an Array in JavaScript is immutable. You can either set an Array's size by defining how many properties will be in there: var a = new Array(2), or by just passing in your values: var a = ['value1', 'value2'].

Answer (score 0):

You mix async with sync approaches here.

`Communications.find` is async but you use it in `getCommi` like sync function.

When you call `getCommi` the function return immediately with empty `array`.

Please change according below.

```
app.factory("getFoo", function(Communications){
 return {
   getCommi: function(val,id, cb){
    var array = [];
    var myVals = Communications.find({
                    filter: {
                        where: {
                            and : [{
                                communications_type_code : val
                            },{
                                object_id : id
                            }]
                        }
                    } 
                }, function(data){
                    for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
                        array[i] = data[i].contact_value;
                    }
                    cb(null, array);
        });   
      }
  }
});
```

and

```
app.controller('usersFormCtrl', ['$scope','getFoo',function($scope,getFoo){
getFoo.getCommi(3,1, function(err, emails){
  $scope.formModel.emails = [];
    for(var index=0; index < $scope.emails.length; index++){
        $scope.emails = emails;
    }
});    
}])
```

**DISCLAIMER** : I don't know angular.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
console.log(array[0].length)
```

Comment: If length is returning `0`, array[0].length will throw error. `Length of undefined`

Comment: can you plz add your javascript code, related to this